# aws lambda functions not refreshing between PC and laptop

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I wrote an update to a lambda function using the editor on the AWS console (the webpage, not my IDE) using my desktop PC then closed and shutdown everything.

The next day I accessed my account via my laptop and logged into the AWS console again and opened the lambda function again.
Although my API gateway was using the new updated function written on my desktop PC, the function shown on my laptop was the old lambda function...
I accidently clicked "save" and it overwrote the lambda function my API gateway was using and suddenly my web app wasn't working anymore because it was running the old lambda code.

So I had to recode the whole new function again because there was no backup of it.

Has anyone else had this problem or know why this happened?

Note:
I had no versioning set, everything was $LATEST
I had saved the update and the API gateway was using the update effectively

My solution after this happened again was to open the lmabda function, close it and open it again on whichever device I wanted to use and the second time it seems to pull up the updated function.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the AWS Lambda web console, and you should file a ticket with AWS.

Comment: I actually had this issue as well, it is definitely a bug. I noticed that if I downloaded the function code it was the updated version, but the console IDE was outdated.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know then it's not something I don't understand or am doing incorrectly...